# 18.04.4, ThinkPad X1 Carbon 7; blank screen after suspend; must reboot

Tags: suspend, power-management, thinkpad

If I shut the lid, the screen blanks but it doesn't appear to be fully suspended (no pulsing lights). When I reopen, screen is blank and doesn't respond to any activity, forcing hard reboot.

Same thing happens when using the suspend from the menu -- blank screen that doesn't respond, also forcing hard reset.

Using 18.04.4 on ThinkPad X1 Carbon 7thGen.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1861837 fixed in 5.3.0-43 kernel (currently available via bionic-propose).

Comment: Hmmm, still happening with 5.3.0-45...